# Domain name not connecting to node.js express web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have an issue, or perhaps an understanding problem with linking my domain with AWS. I will use the `xy.ro` domain as an example.

I have the `xy.ro` domain registered with `easyhost.com`. On AWS I have a node.js express web app.

My `xy.ro` domain is not working as it does not point to anything.

I tried to create a **hosted zone** on AWS with the `xy.ro` domain and tried to create a dataset for this domain but it does not work.

I tried to find step by step instructions also on AWS and other providers but I did not find anything.

Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Please edit your question to include details for _what_ you have configured on easy of EasyHost and AWS. For example, what type of record did you create? What is configured on EasyHost? What is configured on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

If your domain `xy.ro` is registered with `easyhost.com` then it would presumably also be using their DNS hosting service to serve your DNS records.

Creating a public hosted zone in AWS won't affect the DNS resolution unless you can migrate your name servers to use Route 53.

I was not able to see steps from `easyhost.com` website, however from the AWS side take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html).

You should be able to copy the name servers and update within easyhost so that it will use Route 53 as your DNS provider instead.